# How to search a std::string for a specific keyword

Tags: c++11

I am attempting to search a std::string for a keyword and return a boolean value, shown below;

```
std::string select_class()
{
    std::string Class;  //Defines the string 'Class'
    std::string user_input;  //Defines the string 'input

    //Tells the user available commands
    std::cout << "Class selection - Available classes = 
    \n\nArcher\nRouge\nWarrior\nMage\n\nCommands: \nset_class - selects your 
    class for this game";

    std::cout << "\ninfo (class_name) - provides information regarding the 
    specific class";

while (true)
{

        std::cin >> user_input;//Asks user to input a command

        if (std::find(user_input,"set_class") == true)//Tests to see if 
        //specific keyword has been inputted
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter your class:";
        }
    }


}
```

I am looking to be able make my if statement inside my while loop return a boolean value (or have an equivalent outcome).

Apologies for the poor formatting as this is my first post.

Comment: Have you looked up what `std::find()` returns?

Comment: Please review this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @John3136 Yes, but I couldn't quite understand how to get it to work.

Comment: @AlexHodges Well if you know it returns an iterator, why ware you comparing it to a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.find`, like so:

```
std::cin >> user_input;//Asks user to input a command

if (user_input.find("set_class") != std::string::npos)//Tests to see if 
//specific keyword has been inputted
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your class:";
}
```